# Jquery blockui with jquery 1.9.1

Tags: jquery, blockui

I have used the plugin on 1.6 and it works fine.

When i try using jquery 1.9.1 i get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined
```

On loading the 'blockui.js'

I cant find any reference on this, is it possible that blockui is not supported on jquery 1.9.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either include the jQuery migrate plugin, update the plugin to not use `$.browser`, or don't upgrade jQuery past 1.8.3.

`$.browser` was removed in version 1.9

> From [jQuery's Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/):
>
> ***Description**: Contains flags for the useragent, read from
> navigator.userAgent. **This property was removed in jQuery 1.9** and is
> available only through the jQuery.migrate plugin. Please try to use
> feature detection instead.*

Comment: I am not using $.browser, who said anything about it, I dont understand

Comment: is it a good idea not to use the latest version of jquery? do you know of any other blockui plugin avialible?

Comment: In many cases you will often need a newer version of jQuery to use a certain jQuery plugin - but in this case you need an older one so you win more than you loose. And I do not know of any other blockUI plugin I'm afraid.